# Are there any slokas/ verses/ scriptures to cure or avoid diseases

Tags: scripture, puranas, health

Since we have this vast documented mythology related things, I am curious to know is there any book or something of this nature that outlines the verses / slokas that one can chant to ward off some diseases or illness or protect us from catching the same.

Comment: The Atharvana Veda is full of such mantras, but they shouldn't be chanted if you don't know what they're doing, otherwise they could have the opposite effect.

Comment: I think reciting sudharshana ashtakam would be a great thing to fight against diseases

Comment: As explained in ayurveda, diseases come because of imbalance of body's Vata(muscles), Pitta(blood pressure), Kapha(fat) which need to be balanced using lifestyle changes. Any person with excess or less obesity,muscles or high/low blood pressure is prone to several diseases because of constant wastage of body's immunity in balancing muscles,fat and blood pressure for a person with unfit eating, sleeping, daily habits. Prayers/slokas can help in increasing person's spirituality and thereby wisdom to bring necessary changes in life.

Answer (score 2):

The folowing shloka from narayaneeyam is vastly popular even among non-Hindus to cure disease:

अस्मिन् परात्मन् ननु पाद्मकल्पे
त्वमित्थमुत्थापितपद्मयोनि: ।
अनन्तभूमा मम रोगराशिं
निरुन्धि वातालयवास विष्णो ॥१३॥

Asmin paraatman nanu paadmakalpe
Tvamitthamutthapita padmayonihi I

Ananta bhooma mama roga raashim,
Nirundhi vaatalaya vaasa vishno. II

Comment: What are the rules of chanting this shloka ?

Comment: I am not aware of any rules, but a relative says you should chant it 18 times a day, preferably after bathing.  You can chant more often if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Subrahmanya bhujangam composed by Sri Adi Shankaracharya is a very powerful hymn to ward off all physical and mental afflictions. 
Few of the shlokas are as below

20. prashAn thendriye nashta samngnye vicheshte, kaphod kArivaktre bhayoth kampi gAthre
       prayANon mukhe mayyanAthe thadhAneem, drutham me dhayALo bhavAgre guham tham

{Hail Guha, Dayalo. During the last moments of my life, when I will have lost control of my senses, when I will have lost consciousness, when I will be unable move my limbs, when I will be emitting foam of phlegm, when my body will be trembling with fear of death, when I will have none to protect me, Thou must hasten to give me darshan}.

21. krithAn thasya dhooteshu chandeshu kopAth, daha chindhi bhindheethi mAm tharja yatsu
       mayUram samAruhya mAbhairi thitvam, purash shakti pAnir mamAyAhi sheegram

{Oh! Lord, when ferocious messengers of the God of Death come to torture me angrily shouting, "Burn him, Kill him", Oh! Lord Thou must hasten to appear before me, riding on your peacock,carrying Shaktivel, to encourage me not to be afraid}.

22. praNam yAsa kruth pAda yosthe pathitvA, prasAdya prabho prArthaye (a)nekavAram
       na vaktum kshamoham thadhAneem krupApdhe, na kAryAnthakAle manA gapyu pekshA

{Oh Merciful Lord! I am prostating to Thy feet often to secure Thy blessings. Oh treasure house of mercy! I offer prayers to please Thee. Thou should not be indifferent towards me during my last moments. At that time I may not have the control and energy to pray to Thee!}.

23. sahasrAnda bhokthA tvayA ShooranAmA, hathas tArakas simhavaktrascha dhaitya
       mamAnthar hridhistham manaklesha mekam, na hamsi prabho kim karomi kva yAmi

{O Lord! Thou hast slain the demon Soora who ruled the thousand universes! So were the demons Taarakasura and Simhavaktra. But Lord,why have you not killed the demon called mental worry which haunts my mind? When it is afflicting me, what will I do? And where will I go [other than you for help] ? }.

24. aham sarvadA dukkha bhArA vasanno, bhavAn deenabandhus tva dhanyam na yAche
       bhavadh bhaktirodham sadA kluptha bAdham, mamAdhim drutham nAsha yo mAsuta tvam

{Oh Son of Uma! I am always troubled by the mental worries. Thou art the friend of helpless! I approach none but you for saving me. Quickly destroy my mental worries as they interfere with my devotion towards Thee!}.

25. apasmAra kushta kshayArsha prameha, jvaronmAdha gulmAdhi rogA mahAntha
       pishAchAshcha sarve bhavatpatra bhoothim, vilokya kshanAth tArakAre dravanthe

{Oh Conqueror of Taraka! Severe epilepsy, leprosy, consumption, lung diseases, venereal diseases, fevers, mental diseases of all types, they run away the moment they see Thy vibhuti contained in a leaf}.

26. drishi skandamoorthih shrutou skandakeerthih, mukhe me pavitram sadA tach-charitram
       kare tasya krityam vapus tasya bhrutyam, guhe santu leenA mamA shesha bhAvA

{Always may I have before my eyes the murthi of Lord Skanda! Always let my ears hear only the praises of Lord Skanda! Always let my mouth sing the praise of Lord Skanda! Always let my hands be of service to the Lord! Always let my body be a servant to the Lord! Let my limbs, thoughts and actions be devoted to Skanda!}.

27. muneenA muthAho nriNAm bhakti bhAjAm, abheeshta pradhA santhi sarvatra devA
       nriNA manthya jAnAm api svArtha dhAne, guhA devam anyam najAne najAne

{In all the worlds there are Devas to grant the boons of sages and great bhaktas. But for the lowly and ordinary devotees, I know not of any other Deity to protect them except Guha!}.

28. kaLathram suthA bandhuvarga pashurvA, naro vAtha nAree gruhe ye madheeyA
       yajantho namanthah stuvantho bhavantham, smaran thascha te santu sarve kumAra

{Oh Lord Kumara! Let my wife, children, relatives, friends, other men and women in our household, venerate Thee! Praise Thee! And always be absorbed in Thy thoughts!}.

29. mrigA pakshiNo dhamshakA ye cha dushtAs, tathA vyAdhayo bhAdha kA ye madhange
       bhavacchakti teekshnAgra bhinnAs sudhoore, vinashyantu te choorNitha krouncha shaile

{Oh! Destroyer of Krauncha Shaila! Let every thing that troubles my body, birds, beasts, insects, severe diseases, be pierced by Thy powerful weapon Vel and taken far away and destroyed}.

30. janithri pithA cha svaputrA parAdham, sahethe na kim devasenAdhi nAtha
       aham chAthibAlo bhavAn loka thAtha, kshamasvAparAdham samastham Mahesha

{Do not the parents overlook the faults of their children? Oh! Chief of the army of Devas! I am a small child. Thou art the Father of the Universe. Oh Mahesha! Forgive all my faults}.

31. namah kekine shaktaye chApi tubhyam, namah chhaga tubhyam namah kukkutAya
       namah sindhave sindhu deshAya tubhyam, punah skanda moorthe namaste namostu

{I bow to Thee, O Peacock (the symbol of Vedas)! I bow to Thee, O Shakti Weapon (Vel is Parashakti herself), I bow to Thee, O Sheep (the symbol of maya tattvam), I bow to Thee, O Rooster (the symbol of Ego), I bow to Thee, O Ocean (the symbol of ananda), I bow to Thee, O Tiruchendur Shrine, I bow to Thee, O Lord Skanda! I bow to Thee again and again! Let all my prostrations reach Thee!}.

32. jayA nanda bhooman jayA pAra dhAman, jayA mogha keerthe jayA nanthamoorthe
       jayA nanda sindho jayA shesha bandho, jaya tvam sadA mukti dhAnesha soono

{O Source of ananda, reveal Thyself! O Embodiment of boundless effulgent light, reveal Thyself! O Lord! who has all pervading glory, reveal Thyself! O Embodiment of bliss, reveal Thyself! O Lord, Thou art the ocean of bliss, reveal Thyself! O Lord who is the friend of all creatures, reveal Thyself! O Lord, Son of Parameshwara, Bestower of liberation, reveal Thy Glory to me and protect me!}.

33. bhujangAkhya vritthena kluptham sthavam yah, pateth bhakti yuktho guham sam pranamya
       suputrAn kaLathram dhanam dheergamAyuh, labheth Skanda sAyujya manthe narrassah.

{That holy devotee, who prostrates to Lord Guha, reciting the Bhujanga stotra daily, with devotion, will be blessed with good sons, good wife, wealth and long life, and at end of his life, will attain eternal bliss with Lord Skanda}.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this one? Post a shloka from that stotra or post the phalashruti of the stotram?

Comment: Green Message

Home Stotras Pilgrimages Festivals Bharatavarsha Ramakrishna Vivekananda Ramana Saints Sadhana Sanskrit Nature Others

Green Message: The Evergreen Messages of Spirituality, Sanskrit and Nature





Home > Sanskrit Mantras & Slokas > Sri Murugan > Subramanya Bhujangam - in sanskrit with meaning - Stotra on Sri SubramanyaSubramanya Bhujangam - in sanskrit with meaning - Stotra on Sri Subramanya- composed by Sri Adi Shankaracharya

श्रीसुब्रह्मण्यभुजङ्गम्

Sri Subramanya Bhujangam

 
Sri Kartikeya 


सदा बालरूपाऽपि विघ्नाद्रिहन्त्री
महादन्तिवक्त्राऽपि पञ्चास्यमान्या ।
विधीन्द्रादि

Comment: Sorry will try once more

Comment: I think you understood me. Just add the verse which says that chanting the shloka or stotra will remove all the mental illness. Don't copy paste entire words or stotra. .You can [edit] your answer.

Comment: Any rules to chant these shlokas for example can a person chant any of these with out the supervision of a guru or seeking advice from a guru, can we chant the shlokas at any point of the day not just after bathing etc.,

Comment: Yes sir. These are slokas hence do  not require formal initiation. Anybody can recite.

Answer (score 1):

> sarva-vyādhi-vināśitvam

(śrī hari-bhakti-vilāsa)

Sound of the Holy Name of Lord Vishnu Destroys All Diseases, Including the Most Chronic Ones

> acyutānanda-govinda-
>   nāmocchāraṇa-bhīṣitaḥ
>   naśyanti sakalā rogāḥ
>   satyaṁ satyaṁ vadāmy aham

(bṛhan-nāradīya purāṇa; śrī hari-bhakti-vilāsa 2.11.353)

> mahā-vyādhi-samācchanno
>   rāja-vadhopāpiditaḥ
>   nārāyaṇeti saṅkīrtya
>   nirāṭaṅko bhaven naraḥ

(agni purāṇa; śrī hari-bhakti-vilāsa 2.11.356)

> na sāmba vyādhijaṁ duḥkhaṁ
>   heyaṁ nānyauṣadhair api
>   hari-nāmauṣadhaṁ pītvā
>   vyādhis tyājyo na saṁśayaḥ

(parāśara-saṁhitā śrī hari-bhakti-vilāsa 2.11.354)

> ādhayo vyādhayo yasya
>   smaraṇān nāma-kīrtanāt
>   tadaiva vilayaṁ yānti
>   tam anantaṁ namāmy aham

(śrī hari-bhakti-vilāsa 2.11.355)

**Sources:**
[Verse Translations](https://lekhan.org/videos/41-Coronavirus-Cure.m4a),
[Lekhan.org](https://lekhan.org/)

Comment: So there's no need to get a vaccine against Coronavirus?

Comment: I have edited the post to avoid such misunderstandings. Once a Guru told his disciple to feel God's presence everywhere. The disciple being not very intelligent went near a maddened elephant and ignored its mahout's advice to stay away stating that he wants feel God's presence near him. The elephant attacked the disciple who went back and complained to his Guru that it was due to his wrong advice that he has been badly injured. The Guru asked the disciple whether he felt God's presence in the mahout's words. The disciple realized his mistake of not using his God given gift of intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

**Atharvaved** is a scripture of charms. It give many [charms](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av.htm) about different diseases.

## V, 4. Prayer to the kushtha-plant to destroy takman (fever).

> 1. Thou that art born upon the mountains, as the most potent of plants, come hither, O kushtha, destroyer of the takman, to drive out from here the takman!
> 2. To thee (that growest) upon the mountain, the brooding-place of the eagle, (and) art sprung from Himavant, they come with treasures, having heard (thy fame). For they know (thee to be) the destroyer of the takman.
> 3. The asvattha-tree is the seat of the gods in the third heaven from here. There the gods procured the kushtha, the visible manifestation of amrita (ambrosia).
> 4. A golden ship with golden tackle moved upon the heavens. There the gods procured the kushtha, the flower of amrita (ambrosia).
> 5. The paths were golden, and golden were the oars; golden were the ships, upon which they carried forth the kushtha hither (to the mountain).
> 6. This person here, O kushtha, restore for me, and cure him! Render him free from sickness for me!
> 7. Thou art born of the gods, thou art Soma's good friend. Be thou propitious to my in-breathing and my out-breathing, and to this eye of mine!
> 8. Sprung in the north from the Himavant (mountains), thou art brought to the people in the east. There the most stiperior varieties of the kushtha were apportioned.
> 9. 'Superior,' O kushtha, is thy name; 'superior' is the name of thy father. Do thou drive out all disease, and render the takman devoid of strength!
> 10. Pain in the head, affliction in the eye, and ailment of the body, all that shall the kushtha heal-a divinely powerful (remedy), forsooth!

## I, 22. Charm against jaundice and related diseases.

> 1. Up to the sun shall go thy heart-ache and thy jaundice: in the colour of the red bull do we eovelop thee!
> 2. We envelop thee in red tints, unto long life. May this person go unscathed, and be free of vellow colour!
> 3. The cows whose divinity is Rohini, they who, moreover, axe (themselves) red (róhinin)-(in their) every form and every strength we do envelop thee.
> 4. Into the parrots, into the ropanâkâs (thrush) do we put thy jaundice, and, furthermore, into the hâridravas (yellow wagtail) do we put thy jaundice.

## VI, 105. Charm against cough.

> 1. As the-soul with the soul's desires swiftly to a distance flies, thus do thou, O cough, fly forth along the soul's course of flight!
> 2. As a well-sharpened arrow swiftly to a distance flies, thus do thou, O cough, fly forth along the expanse of the earth!
> 3. As the rays of the sun swiftly to a distance fly, thus do thou, O cough, fly forth along the flood of the sea!

## VI, 90. Charm against internal pain (colic), due to the missiles of Rudra.

> 1. The arrow that Rudra did cast upon thee, into (thy) limbs, and into thy heart, this here do we now draw out away from thee.
> 2. From the hundred arteries which are distributed along thy limbs, from all of these do we exorcise forth the poisons.
> 3. Adoration be to thee, O Rudra, as thou casteth (thy arrow); adoration to the (arrow) when it has been placed upon (the bow); adoration to it as it is being hurled; adoration to it when it has fallen down!