# Is it possible to cure diseases by accumulating good karma?

Tags: karma, health

Everything that happens to us is due to good or bad karma.

If we hurt people we will get bad karma and we might suffer due to it.

So if someone got a disease(for example cancer) she might have done something wrong in her life(bad karma).
Now she if she does good karma(like feeding the poor) she will get good karma.

Will that good karma cure her cancer without any medications or therapy?

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9469/are-there-any-slokas-verses-scriptures-to-cure-or-avoid-diseases

Comment: Brahma Sutras says the Lord is the dispenser of karma. When it will fructify is known only to the Lord. The fruits of doing good karma - or bad karma - in this life may not occur in this life but in later lifes. See also https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19644/does-prayer-remove-bad-deeds-of-past-lives/19653#19653